# Input element with padding and percentage width exceeds parent div

Tags: html, css, padding

I have this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>

div{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 300px;
}

input{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I need the input to be 100% of the parent div, but also I need this input to have 10px padding. Results can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/pdJYF/

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to your input field:

```
input{
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

- [**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pdJYF/3/)
- [**Browser Compatibility**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)

---

The underlying "problem" is the box model of HTML/CSS. As you can see in the [illustration of the respective MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) each element's box has 4 different areas: margin box, border box, padding box and content box.

When you assign measures (`width` or `height`) to the element, this is applied to one of these areas. If the area is, e.g., the content box, then for the total size of the element margin, border and padding is added. So you wont set the total dimensions of the box, but one of its contained boxes.

The CSS property [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) tells the browser, which box to use, when calculating the element's dimensions. The default value is `content-box`. So in the above example values for margin, border and padding get added and hence the element is too big. By setting the box model to `border-box`, only the margin gets added to the dimensions (which is zero here) and the elements fits.

Comment: Hi @Sirko, can you please explain what happens here and why this property fixes the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must decrease 2x padding from left and right, and decrease 2x for any pixel you want use like this and insert your input's width.

For example: 20px (paddings left & right) + 2px (borders left & Right )= 22px

300px - 22px = 278px

> div { border: 1px solid red; width:300px; }
>
> input { width: 278px;padding: 10px; }

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't put the padding in percentage too:

```
input{
   width: 94%;
   padding: 0 3%;
   border:0;
}
```